# EFCore - Eager Data Loading produce huge response on Scoped DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i've got a problem using Asp NET .Core 6 and EntityFramework Core, while building a simple ToDo App: there are some Entities related together, there is the Auth Logic based on JWT Token and there are, obviously, same API Endpoint.

My DbContext has been registered on Startup.cs as a Scoped Service and is injected into each repositories used to manage/get entities.

During my Auth Process and Data Validation (all made in the same request) i'm loading some navigation properties using `.Include()` statement as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager.

`Include()` are "stored" into the scoped DbContext and they will be used for all Queries in my app to always load related entities. This produce an unexpected huge JSON response (240 Mb to retrieve 15 records).

I've tried to limit the Serialization using

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

But without any difference.

How can i remove the previously Included navigation properties in my Scoped DbContext?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show your query? As well as your db model classes?

Comment: I could not show my query because they are more then once, across multiple Repositories. The problem is that the DbContext remember that i want to include "Todos" and then, will always load "Todos" navigation properties on all entities, recursively

Comment: DbContext remember that i want to include "Todos" 
What do you mean by that? Is it on a specific class? Can we see your class and it's related classes? Maybe you just need to change some navigational property

Comment: If you've previously loaded an entity and included some of its navigation properties, when you load the same entity on the same context, you'll get the same reference returned, so it will already have those navigation properties populated.

Comment: The simple answer is "don't pass entities". Use projection to populate a view model containing just the data that needs to be sent. That way it doesn't matter what data happens to have been previously eager loaded, your delivered object will not be a serialized entity but rather a detached ViewModel/DTO composed by EF via `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` method.

Comment: Also, a key architectural/procedural principle should be to *never load entire entities in validation logic*. It's always possible to do database-based validations without loading entities. This principle prevents lots of unexpected bugs and as a bonus often makes validation a lighter process.